# Python IMAP - Read Gmail with '+' in email address

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, imap, gmail-imap

I've previously used imaplib in Python 3to extract emails from gmail. However I would want to generate a script to differentiate emails to the same address with different strings after a plus sign. For example, the base email address can be:

```
example@gmail.com
```

Then I would want to separately read all emails with the addresses:

```
example+test1@gmail.com,
example+test2@gmail.com,
example@gmail.com.
```

Therefore I would wind up with a dictionary of lists containing the specific emails. This only works for `example@gmail.com`. For example:

```
{'example':[],
 'example_test':[],
 'example_test2':[]}
```

Currently I can retrieve the emails that I need with this function from a class:

```
def get_emails(self):
    """Retrieve emails"""
    self.M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.server)
    self.M.login(self.emailaddress,self.password)
    self.M.select(readonly=1)
    self.M.select('INBOX', readonly=True)
    #Yesterdays date
    date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(self.daysback)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
    print("Selecting email messages since %s" % date)
    #Retrieve all emails from yesterday on
    result,data = self.M.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date))
    return result,data
```

Comment: specifically what's your goal here? what's going wrong?

Comment: Reading from IMAP shows the entire email box, I want to filter down the results, to only read specific filters that were created in Gmail

Comment: Do you have them filtered to a label/folder in Gmail?  If so, read that folder.

Comment: Did you try `result,data = self.M.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date), ('TO example+test1@gmail.com'))`

Comment: @SergeBallesta, that seems to work! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should directly use the exact mail address you want in the IMAP search request. For example it could be something like :

```
result,data = self.M.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date),
    ('TO example+test1@gmail.com'))
```